# Solutions for the ODE: $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-v^2)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

According to [this](https://www.math24.net/bessel-differential-equation/) site, if $v$ is non-integer the solution of

$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-v^2)y=0\tag1$$

is

$$y(x)=C_1J_v(x)+C_2J_{-v}(x).\tag2$$

Where $J_v(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

In my BETA mathematics handbook, they have this form of the Bessel differential equation:

$$x^2y''+xy'+(a^2x^2-v^2)y=0,\tag3$$

and they claim the solution is

$$y(x)=C_1J_v(ax)+C_2Y_v(ax),\tag4$$

Where $Y_v(x)$ is the Weber function. Setting $a=1$ then$(1)=(3)$ but still the solution number $(4)$ will be different from solution $(2)$:

$$y(x)=C_1J_v(x)+C_2Y_v(x).$$

Does this imply that $J_{-v}=Y_v?$

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Weber_functions

Comment: $Y_v$ is not the same as $J_{-v}$. You can find the expression for $Y_v$ in terms of Bessel functions of the first kind [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_second_kind:_Yα).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth - I figured that, but how does one explain those two different answers to the same differential equation then?

Comment: The $C_1$ and $C_2$ from the two sources are not the same. It's like how the solution to $y'' = a^2 y$ (where $a > 0$) could be written as $C_1 e^{ax} + C_2 e^{-ax}$ or as $C_1 \cosh(ax) + C_2 \sinh (ax)$ (or in general, $C_1 y_1(x) + C_2 y_2(x)$ where $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are any two *linearly independent linear combinations of $e^{ax}$ and $e^{-ax}$*).

Comment: They are the same answer, since $Y_v$ is a linear combination of $J_v$ and $J_{-v}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non-integer $v$ the following relation holds:

$$
Y_v(x)=\frac{J_v(x)\cos v\pi-J_{-v}(x)}{\sin v\pi}
$$

so that both answers are correct up to redefinition of constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

The advantage of the equation $(4)$ is the fact that it is valid for integer $v$ as well.